# How to rewrite/use jquery code in Angular 2

Tags: jquery, function, angular, typescript

Hello I build website about whisky :) and I need to use some code (calc height of elements by class .calcheight) from query. How to rewrite this code? I mean how to create function (typescript who return number) and how to select elements because I don't want use jQuery?

Angular2:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { WhiskyService } from './whisky.service';
import { Whisky } from './whisky.interface';

@Component({
    selector: 'whisky-grid',
    host: {
      class: 'ui grid'
    },
    templateUrl: 'app/whisky.component.html',
    providers: [WhiskyService]
})

export class AppComponent {

    whiskyList: Array<Whisky>;

    constructor(private _whiskyService: WhiskyService) { }


    getWhisky() {
        this.whiskyList = this._whiskyService.getWhisky();
    }


    ngOnInit() {
        this.getWhisky();
    }

}
```

And jquery:

```
var CalcHeight = function(){

        function getMaxHeight(el){
            var element = $(el);
            var height = 0;
            element.each(function() {
                if(height < $(this).height()) {
                    height = $(this).height();
                }
            });
            return height;
        }

        function setHeight(el, value){
            var element = $(el);
            element.each(function() {
                $(this).height(value);
            });
        }

        function setParam(el, param, block){
            $(block).css(param, getMaxHeight(el));
        }

        function render(el) {
            setHeight(el, getMaxHeight(el));
        }

        return {
            getMaxHeight : getMaxHeight,
            setParam : setParam,
            init : function (el){
                render(el);
            }
        }
    }();
CalcHeight.init('.calcheight');
```

Comment: what is this function supposed to achieve? by the looks of it it sets all elements to the same max height. I'm sure there's better ways of doing that in pure css..

Comment: thank you for your answer but this is example I have many jQuery snippets and I want use it :) But I don't know how to create function (in typescript because I see some thing like this functionName(): void {} or boolean) and how to select element like get.ElementById but in typescript.

Comment: js code is perfectly valid typescript code as well.. there's no special way to create functions in typescript..

Comment: Can anybody give me an example? :)